# Exception in inner catch in java

Tags: java, exception

In below code Exception is raised inside the inner catch block, so ideally it should be caught by outer catch block and it should result in Normal execution.
But when I executed, it is not caught in outer catch block still executed normally without any stack trace.

My doubt is, if it has  executed normally (without stack trace) then it must have been caught by outer catch("10" should have been printed)

Code:

```
public class Test2 {


    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            System.out.println("2");

            System.out.println("3");
            try {
                System.out.println("4");
                System.out.println("5");

                System.out.println("6");

                }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                int x=1/0;
            }
            finally
            {
                System.out.println("8");

            }
            System.out.println("9");
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println("10");
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("11");
        }
        System.out.println("12");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
11
12
```

Comment: I don't see any code that throws a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NullPointerException` is just not thrown anywhere in your code. As a result, the execution never gets to that catch block that has division by zero, so arithmetic exception is not raised either.

Try adding something like the following after `System.out.println("6");`:

```
Object obj = null;
obj.toString();
```

to make `NullPointerException` be thrown.

Comment: Why not simply throw a NPE?

Comment: I tried to model a ... realistic scenario: most of NPEs in the wild are thrown by VM :) But sure, a more straightforward approach is to just do `throw new NullPointerException()`

Answer (score 0):

Little Change in your code :

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            System.out.println("2");
            System.out.println("3");
            try {
                System.out.println("4");
                System.out.println("5");
            System.out.println("6");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("Inner Catch Block");
                int x = 1 / 0;
            } finally {
                System.out.println("8");
            }
            System.out.println("9");
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("10");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("11");
        }
        System.out.println("12");
    }
}
```

As no exception has occurred in the inner try block, inner catch block did not execute. See `Inner Catch Block` did not print. `finally`block was executed and rest of the code of inner try block executed. Similarly, as no exception has occurred in the outer try block, outer catch block also did not execute.

Answer (score 0):

The only line that would throw an exception would be when you initialize x.
If you're attempting to see this exception, you would have to move it to one of the try blocks. Also it throws an ArithmeticException **not** a NullPointerException, so you would have to change your catch block to either ArithmeticException or a general Exception. Example below.

```
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println("3");
        try {
            int x = 1 / 0;
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("4");
            System.out.println("5");
            System.out.println("6");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("8");
        }
        System.out.println("9");
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("10");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("11");
    }
    System.out.println("12");
}
```